# how click a button on a web site in vb 6.0

Tags: browser, vb6, controls

how can i click a button on website given that i have the web browser control in my visual basic 6.0 i need it for my project where i want to automatically click a button from a series of buttons

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the "click" event on the element.

This will cause all the client-side actions to happen as if the user clicked it with the mouse.